# How to get specific part of a string from each list item?

Tags: python, list

How can I extract the id that comes after the string 'worldandplaces/place-review/' and save into separate python list? ID is not always present for every item on the list. And if there is an item without the ID I would like to add it also to the new list as 'none'.

My efforts so far:

```
myString =[" --------------- userLang: en-us  refUrl: worldandplaces/place-review/12345-6789-d1e2-4444-907e555ce5d5 Email address: johndoe@gmail.com", " --------------- userLang: en-us  refUrl: worldandplaces/place-review/09876-5432-c3d3-9999-307e555ce665 Email address: janedoe@gmail.com", "------ userLang: en-us refUrl: worldandplaces/ Email address: janedoe@gmail.com"]


placeID =[]

for entry in myString:
    try:
        placeID.extend([f for f in entry.split(' ') if f.startswith('worldandplaces')])
    except:
        placeID.append('none')
```

currentResult:

```
['worldandplaces/place-review/12345-6789-d1e2-4444-907e555ce5d5', 'worldandplaces/place-review/09876-5432-c3d3-9999-307e555ce665']
```

expectedResult:

```
['12345-6789-d1e2-4444-907e555ce5d5', '09876-5432-c3d3-9999-307e555ce665', 'none']
```

Comment: ```if f.startswith(...)```, it will add the element **only** if the string startswith ```worldandplaces```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply find out where the prefix `worldandplaces/place-review/` is located and pick the id after that:

```py
myString = [" --------------- userLang: en-us  refUrl: worldandplaces/place-review/12345-6789-d1e2-4444-907e555ce5d5 Email address: johndoe@gmail.com", " --------------- userLang: en-us  refUrl: worldandplaces/place-review/09876-5432-c3d3-9999-307e555ce665 Email address: janedoe@gmail.com", "------ userLang: en-us refUrl: worldandplaces/ Email address: janedoe@gmail.com"]

placeID = []
target = 'worldandplaces/place-review/'
lentarget = len(target)
for entry in myString:
    try:
        idx = entry.index(target) + lentarget
        substr = entry[idx:]
        placeID.append(substr.split(' ')[0])
    except Exception as e:
        placeID.append('none')

print(placeID)
```

Output as requested.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using regex [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall)

```
import re


myString = [
    " --------------- userLang: en-us  refUrl: worldandplaces/place-review/12345-6789-d1e2-4444-907e555ce5d5 Email address: johndoe@gmail.com",
    " --------------- userLang: en-us  refUrl: worldandplaces/place-review/09876-5432-c3d3-9999-307e555ce665 Email address: janedoe@gmail.com",
    "------ userLang: en-us refUrl: worldandplaces/ Email address: janedoe@gmail.com",
]
placeID = []

for entry in myString:
    # Option 1: If an entry can contain multiple occurrences
    occurrences = re.findall(r"worldandplaces/place-review/([\S]*)", entry)
    placeID.extend(occurrences or ['none'])

    # Option 2: If an entry only has 1 occurrence
    # occurrence = re.search(r"worldandplaces/place-review/([\S]*)", entry)
    # placeID.append(occurrence.group(1) if occurrence else 'none')

print(placeID)
```

Output

```
['12345-6789-d1e2-4444-907e555ce5d5', '09876-5432-c3d3-9999-307e555ce665', 'none']
```

Answer (score 0):

This will produce the required output.

```py
myString = [
    " --------------- userLang: en-us  refUrl: worldandplaces/place-review/12345-6789-d1e2-4444-907e555ce5d5 Email address: johndoe@gmail.com",
    " --------------- userLang: en-us  refUrl: worldandplaces/place-review/09876-5432-c3d3-9999-307e555ce665 Email address: janedoe@gmail.com",
    "------ userLang: en-us refUrl: worldandplaces/ Email address: janedoe@gmail.com",
]

placeID = []

for entry in myString:
  try:
    placeID.extend(
        [f.split("/")[2] for f in entry.split(" ") if f.startswith("worldandplaces")]
    )
  except IndexError:
    placeID.append('none')

print(placeID)
```

```
OUTPUT
['12345-6789-d1e2-4444-907e555ce5d5', '09876-5432-c3d3-9999-307e555ce665', 'none']
```

Comment: Did you test the code: ```IndexError: list index out of range```

Comment: Oops, for some reason I posted without the try/except block.